# how to speed up breadth-first-search in a undirected graph

Tags: algorithm

I think we can use queue to do the breadth-first-search(BFS) traversal, and since add() and remove() in queue is constant time, so I think BFS traversal from a starting node to the target node is linear time.

But how to speed up BFS? is there a data structure that can reduce this time complexity?

Comment: I would recommend avoiding acronyms, as you can't assume everyone knows what BFS stands for (i assume its Breadth-first search)

Comment: @ZachSpencer: I think one can pretty much assume that people know what BFS means in the context of graph algorithms. I still think it's a good idea to link to the wikipedia article or something

Comment: I agree *most* people will know what BFS means.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can speed up BFS from a source to a target by doing a **[bi-directional search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bidirectional_search)**.

A bi-directional search is basically doing a BFS from the source and from the target at the same time, one step from each - until the two fronts meet each other.

**Why is it better?**

- A BFS at worst case discovers `O(B^d)` nodes (`B` is the branch
  factor, the degree of each node) - and `d` is the depth fo the
  solution.
- A bi-directional BFS at worst case discovers `O(B^(d/2)*2)=O(B^(d/2))` nodes, which
  is usually much smaller

Empirically, a bi-directional search is usually faster than regular BFS for large/infinite graphs.

Comment: Haha, I lost track of how often you brought up bi-diretional graph search on [algorithm] :D Surprising how often this comes up

Comment: @NiklasB. From my experience - it is so much faster than the alternatives for uninformed and unweighted graphs, why not share the knowledge?

Comment: Sure, I actually didn't know the concept before. There's absolutely nothing wrong with it, it's pretty cool

Comment: Thanks. It is indeed reduce the number of nodes traversed, but the time is still linear, right?

Comment: @aminy: Yes, the runtime is linear. And it needs to be, because it needs to consider all nodes and edges in the worst case, so linear time is a lower bound for this algorithm

Answer (score -1):

The worst case time is linear in the number of nodes (and that can clearly be attained). You can speed up the search via heuristics, i.e., instead of adding the new nodes to a queue add them to a priority queue, where the priority is some measure of how near the new node seems to be to the goal.

Another way to speed it up is to work in paralell, i.e., farm out the queue of nodes to be processed to worker threads. But then you get the hassle of making sure no (or at least not too many) nodes get visited more than once.

Unless the graphs you are trying to process are truly huge, I wouldn't worry too much about this, there is little to be squeezed out here performance-wise. *Measure* where the bottlenecks of your system are, and concentrate on them. And do this only if the performance isn't enough, otherwise spend your time at the beach (or whatever you like to do best).

Comment: BFS is so oftenly used on infinite graphs in the field of artificial intelligence where the graph is a states graph. I don't like your suggestion to avoid optimizing it at all.

Comment: The worst case time of a breadth-first search is quadratic in the number of nodes, as opposed to linear. It is however linear in the number of edges.

Comment: @Gassa, impossible. BFS will visit each node exactly once if the search fails.

Comment: Right, we visit each node no more than once. But how do we traverse up to N edges from each one node in constant time? Here, N is the number of nodes.

Comment: OK, here is a graph for you. It consists of vertices named 1, 2, 100-199 and 200-299 (202 vertices in total). We search for a path from 1 to 2. There are 100 edges 1-1XX (that is, 1-100, 1-101, ..., 1-199), 10000 edges 1XX-2YY and 100 edges 2YY-2, a total of 10200 edges. Now, while visiting vertices 1XX, we have to consider all 10000 edges to 2YY from them. If we don't, consider adding one edge to the graph, e.g., 134-2, changing the shortest path. We won't be sure there is no such edge from 1XX to 2 unless we consider them all.